# Модальное окно в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Задача состоит в том, что нужно открывать модальное окно в модальном окне.
Теперь о проблеме:
Использую fancybox 2. Первое модальное окно открывается нормально, но при клике на ссылку в этом модальном окне нужно открывать еще одну модалку, а предыдущую скрывать. 
Я делал все по аналогии как и на первой модалке, т.е. давал ссылке во внутреннем модальном окне href="#block-id", но при клике вместо открытия окна, выдает окно с ошибкой.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя тупость и как решить проблему.

Comment: "**открывать модальное окно в модальном окне**" Вы заставили меня пересмотреть всю свою жизнь. Неужто "модальное окно" теперь означает что-то другое?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9byw9y0u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html,body{
height:100%;
}
.main{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
background:white;
}
.mdl{
position:absolute;
top:50%; left:50%;
width:800px;
height:400px;
background:#fefefe;
margin:-200px -400px;
display:none;
z-index:11;
}
.btn1,.btn2{
display:block;
width:200px;
padding:8px 0;
background:lightgreen;
margin:0 40px;
text-align:center;
cursor:pointer;
}
.js{
position:fixed;
top:0; left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
z-index:10;
display:none;
}
.mdl1{
width:300px;
height:150px;
background:pink;
position:absolute;
left:50%; margin-left:-150px;
top:50%; margin-top:-75px;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<a class="btn1">Открыть первое окно</a>
 <div class="mdl"> 
   <a class="btn2">Открыть второе окно</a>
   <div class="mdl1"> 
    <p class="close">X</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="js"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js").click(function(){
        $(".mdl").hide();
        $(".js").hide();
    });
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".mdl").show();
        $(".js").show();
    });
});

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".mdl1").hide();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $(".mdl1").show();
    });
});

</script>
```

Вот так собственно это делается , код прозрачен и всё достаточно ясно

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное!

Comment: ради Бога , это пример но не профи уровень

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а как это сделать на чистом javascript-e

Comment: я не умею на нативном js это делать ... не учил , мне jquery за глаза хаватет